# All domain names showing up in a single ssl certificate

Tags: ssl

I just installed a Cloudflare Origin CA ssl certificate on my server. Because I have many domains on this server, I configured the certificate to protect them all, so I can use only one certificate for all my domains (domain1.com, domain2.com, etc...).

I went to check my ssl was working properly with the service whynopadlock.com, and I realized this service can list ALL of my domain names on the server by just accessing domain1.com? Are all the domains in a certificate meant to be public, is this normal behavior and can I avoid it?

I also noticed whynopadlock.com lists some domains in the certificate that are not mine. Does it mean Cloudflare is using the same certificate for many different users?

Comment: Certificates are public. You should stop worrying about names in them.

Answer (score 1):

> Are all the domains in a certificate meant to be public, is this normal behavior and can I avoid it?

All certificate [subject alternate names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name) are part of the certificate and are sent to every client that tries to connect securely.

There is no way to avoid it unless you want to use separate certificates for each domain.

> I also noticed whynopadlock.com lists some domains in the certificate that are not mine.

Cloudflare states that [this is normal](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/204144518-SSL-FAQ#h_293541339461548959928672):

> **Are Cloudflare SSL certificates shared?**
>
> Universal SSL certificates are shared across multiple domains for
>   multiple customers.  If certificate sharing is a concern, Cloudflare
>   recommends a [Dedicated or Custom SSL certificate](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203295200).

Note that Cloudflare (as of Feb 2019) does provide [dedicated certificates](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/228009108-Dedicated-SSL-Certificates) if you do not want to use a shared certificate.